# ajuda com SELECT, help me with select mysql

Tags: mysql

Table Usuarios

```
usuario_id | name
    20     | Jose
    22     | Maria
```

Table Pacientes

```
paciente_id | usuario_id
    10      |    20
```

Table Funcionarios

```
funcionario_id | usuario_id | CRM
      3        |    22      | 342-BA
```

Table Consultas_medicas

```
id | paciente_id | funcionario_id | date  |  time
 1 |      10     |        3       | 11/11 |  13:30
```

I need to perform a Select in the consultas_medicas table and give me the name of paciente_id, and the name of funcionario_id

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    usuarios as u 
INNER JOIN 
   funcionarios as f 
INNER JOIN 
   consultas_medicas as c 
INNER JOIN 
   pacientes as c 
ON 
   (u.id=f.usuario_id) 
and 
   (c.funcionario_id=f.funcionario_id)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Edit your question. Don't put the translation in a comment.

Comment: i'm sorry, bro.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: I think it's a little strange to include a usuario_id in a funcionario table - but maybe something has got a little lost in (my) transalation.

Answer (score 0):

Taking what you have written above, I'm going to assume that this is your basic schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE usuarios
(
    usuario_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (usuario_id)
);

CREATE TABLE pacientes 
(
    paciente_id INT NOT NULL,
    usuario_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (paciente_id, usuario_id)
);

CREATE TABLE funcionarios 
(
    funcionario_id INT NOT NULL,
    usuario_id INT NOT NULL,
    CRM VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (funcionario_id)
);

CREATE TABLE consultas_medicas
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    paciente_id INT NOT NULL,
    funcionario_id INT NOT NULL,
    date VARCHAR(255),
    time VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE pacientes ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(usuario_id);
ALTER TABLE funcionarios ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(usuario_id);
ALTER TABLE consultas_medicas ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (paciente_id) REFERENCES pacientes(paciente_id);
ALTER TABLE consultas_medicas ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (funcionario_id) REFERENCES funcionarios(funcionario_id);

INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (20, 'Jose'), (22, 'Maria');
INSERT INTO pacientes VALUES (10, 20);
INSERT INTO funcionarios VALUES (3, 22, '342-BA');
INSERT INTO consultas_medicas VALUES (1, 10, 3, '11/11', '13:30');
```

If so, the query that you provided is using the `c` alias twice, and the `usuarios` table's primary key is `usuario_id` and not just `id`.

And if that's so, then this query should work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
    usuarios as u 
INNER JOIN 
   funcionarios as f 
INNER JOIN 
   consultas_medicas as c 
INNER JOIN 
   pacientes as p
ON 
   (u.usuario_id=f.usuario_id) 
and 
   (c.funcionario_id=f.funcionario_id)
```

That query will result in several duplicate column names, specifically `usuario_id` will be returned three times, so you'll need to alias those as well (or your code will need to know how to deal with it), but this should hopefully get you on the correct path.

Alternatively, if you really don't need to join with the `usuarios` table, you can simplify it a bit:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    pacientes p
LEFT JOIN
    consultas_medicas c
ON
    p.paciente_id = c.paciente_id
LEFT JOIN
    funcionarios f
ON
    c.funcionario_id = f.funcionario_id
```

Comment: I don't understand your aliasing - and NEVER use evil `SELECT *` - ok, I understand your aliasing, but it's a little unconventional to join the tables in that way. `JOIN...ON` seems like a nice convention.

Comment: @Strawberry, the aliases and `*` comes from the OP's original post, and the join syntax comes from 20 years of habit ;)